# ERROR: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'updated_at' in 'field list'

Tags: php, html, laravel

So basically the error states that i don't have a column called updated_at but i know i dont have it and i dont want to have it. My database table only has the following columns : requester, user_requested, id, status.

this is my model

```
class Friendships extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['requester', 'user_requested', 'status'];
}
```

this is my profilecontroller

```
 public function sendRequest($id){
        return Auth::user()->addFriend($id);

  }
```

And this is my friendable.php

```
namespace App\Traits;
use App\Friendships;

trait Friendable{
    public function test(){
        return 'hi' ;
    }

    public function addFriend($id){
        $Friendship = Friendships::create([
                'requester' => $this->id,
                'user_requested' => $id
        ]);


        if($Friendship){
            return $Friendship;
        }
        return  'failed';
    }


}
```

it says that method addFriend isnt found and the create doesnt work apparently because the id isnt found.

Comment: Try `public $timestamps = false;` in model and check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, Eloquent expects `created_at` and `updated_at` columns to exist on your tables. If you do not wish to have these columns automatically managed by Eloquent, set the  `$timestamps` property on your model to `false`:

```
class Friendships extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $fillable = ['requester', 'user_requested', 'status'];
}
```

**EDIT**

fire commands,

```
php artisan make:migration modify_friendships_table;
```

Then go to migration file which is generated in `database/migrations`

Write code in that class,

```
Schema::table('friendships', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->boolean("status")->default(0)->change();
});
```

save above file, then fire below command

```
php artisan migrate
```

And now check, if its working.

Comment: it worked, thanks! but now it shows this error :General error: 1364 Field 'status' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `friendships` (`requester`, `user_requested`) values (1, 1))

Comment: If you want to set `status` as null if not set anything, then you have to create new migration script to alter that column to set null if not set any value. Here is [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations#modifying-columns) for alter column. I made changes in answer. Now check.

Comment: but my status is a boolean

Answer (score 1):

Laravel will automatically try to set the value for `created_at` and `updated_at` fields. It is highly recommended to have these, however if you don't want to you can disable them on your Model.

To do this simply add `public $timestamps = false;` to the model. For example:

```php
class Friendships extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $fillable = ['requester', 'user_requested', 'status'];
}
```

Comment: it worked, thanks! but now it shows this error :General error: 1364 Field 'status' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into friendships (requester, user_requested) values (1, 1)